# How to use X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION to handle payments on behalf of other users in PayPal with out knowing user's email address

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

We are developing a marketplace webapp which charges customers on behalf of sellers.

After reading through PayPal's API documentation, the only solution seems to be the [Permissions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/permissions/) service.

According to the documentation. After retrieving the `access token` and `token secrete` of a seller through the `RequestPermissions` call, we generated X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header to initiate an express checkout `payment id`. However, the `payment id` generated is associated with our PayPal account instead of the seller's, which is not the anticipated behavior.

Adding seller's email address in the `SUBJECT` field as noted in [PayPal Name-Value Pair API Basics](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/) does work, but as we tested it, it has nothing to do with the `access token` and `token secrete`.

The problem with the `SUBJECT` field is that we cannot make sure the seller's email address with us is the one PayPal have on file.

The `GetBasicPersonalData` permission seems to be able to get a valid email address, but that needs to be pre-approved by PayPal. In fact, I have come across many websites that does not require this permission but able to initiate payment on behalf of other users. Is there a way to just get sellers' email or PayPal Id without `GetBasicPersonalData` permission? We don't actually need any other personal data except email or PayPal Id.

Comment: Hey @ericls did you ever figure out the solution to this problem? Can you please let me know if you did. I am struggling with this right now, and the PayPal documentation is literally useless.

Comment: @Aaron We end up changed everything to use the NVP APIs.

Comment: thanks for the response lol. Damn, I am hoping to move away from NVP and get on board this and use Parallel Payments, but it's proving to be very difficult :(

Comment: Can you share how you accomplished this with NVP?

Comment: @Aaron geeks! whats latest on this?